# I need mysql sink connector jar file to pull data from kafka

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I need mysql sink connector jar file  to pull data from kafka which contain the SinkConnector.class file

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "MySQL sink connector jar".

There's Confluent's JDBC sink connector, which can be found from Confluent Hub website. This can be used with most databases offering JDBC drivers. It can also be used in any Kafka environment, not only Confluent Platform/Cloud.

Then there's the MySQL JDBC **Driver JAR**, which can be downloaded from MySQL website... but different drivers exist based on the server version, so make sure you get the correct one